# CSS text in vertical height

Tags: css

```
text-align: center;
box-sizing: border-box;
color: #fff;
float: left;
width: 50%;
height: 65vh;
padding-top: 14%
```

That's my CSS. What I want is the text to be precisely in the middle, but it won't work since my height depends on the screen height. How may I fix this?

Comment: Play around with line-height.

Comment: `line-height: 100px` (or your height value), and remove `padding-top`, `heigh` properties.

Comment: but if I do the 100px as line-height, it won't be responsive?

Comment: please could you share a basic markup and a sample of the text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Flexbox layout.

Good guide for Flexbox: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

**display: flex** set layout to flexbox layout

**justify-content: center** set text to horizontal center

**align-items: center** set text to vertical center

```css
.container {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border: 3px solid black;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <p class="text">Some Text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: It works perfect. Now let's say that I use the code (which works perfectly, thanks) but I want to use this on another div below. Then I've a problem since there's different heights. 65vh and 35vh. Please help!

Comment: @Cooln How are these two divs placed? on top of each other? One inside another? If would be better if you could share some HTML

Answer (score 0):

You could use `display:table-cell`

```css
.container {
  width: 150px;
  height: 65vh;
  border: 3px solid black;
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p class="text">Some Text</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the `line-height` to be the same as your `height` value (`65vh`):

https://jsfiddle.net/bq7kLf99/

Comment: Only works for one line of text that doesn't wrap - https://jsfiddle.net/bq7kLf99/1/